# getting title value from multiple span tag

Tags: javascript

i have a multiple li tag with tag, since the span is within the li tags they have the same id name.
    i want to be able to get the value within the span tag when a paticular li tag is selected.
     here my html 
code

```
<li>
    <form action="" method="post" name="topdivform">
        <span id="editedpart" title="first div"><a href="#" title="edit" id="edit" onclick="showeditpage()">first div</a></span>
    </form>
</li>
<li>
    <form action="" method="post" name="topdivform">
        <span id="editedpart" title="second div"><a href="#" title="edit" id="edit" onclick="showeditpage()">second div</a></span>
    </form>
</li>
<li>
    <form action="" method="post" name="topdivform">
        <span id="editedpart" title="third div"><a href="#" title="edit" id="edit" onclick="showeditpage()">third div</a></span>
    </form>
</li>
```

and here is my javascript

```
var elem = document.getElementById("editedpart");
var str ="";
for(var i = 0; i< elem.length; ++i){
    str = elem[i].innerText;
    alert(str);

}
```

it is not getting the text insidethe span tag
thanks

Comment: [jQuery.](http://jquery.com) Also, no two elements should share an `id`.

Comment: `document.getElementById` returns single object. you can't use like this and Id should be unique.

Comment: Instead of using id for "editedpart", use a data-* attribute or a class attribute.

Comment: Why are you using forms when you don't have any form controls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are giving the same id to multiple elements, there is no way to predict which element will be returned by the call to GetElementById. You'll need to restructure your markup to avoid giving multiple elements the same id.

Comment: Lyn Headley,how am i going to do that so that i can get the value without writing too much code

Comment: @user1496307 you should be concerned with writing as much code as you need to. =)

Answer (score 2):

```
var elem = document.getElementsByName("topdivform");

var str ="";
for(var i = 0; i< elem.length; ++i){
    str = elem[i].textContent || elem[i].innerText;
    alert(str);
}
```

If you need to be more specific in your DOM selection, you can use `querySelectorAll()`, though it's not supported in IE6/7.

```
var elem = document.querySelectorAll("li > form[name=topdivform] > span > a[title=edit]");
```

Comment: am not i am, i have use your method but it is either show the first span or the last one

Answer (score 0):

You could add an eventlistener (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener) to the click event of the li's and set a global variable from the child span node as your select value. You could use a class name (`<span class="isSelected"></span>`) or `data-*` (`<span data-selected="true"></span>`) to denote which span is "selected" during the click event. The first one is nice because you just change that value as needed. The second one requires you to parse the DOM and replace that attribute or class each time the selection changes.